# How to get the dirname / path were the user executed the script?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying get the directory where the user typed the command (executed the node script).

For example with an npm 'script' :

```
const program = require('commander');

program
  .command('get')
  .action(() => {
    console.log(); // <-- should return the current directory like a 'pwd' command
  });

program.parse(process.argv)
```

Note : i'm not trying to get the path were the node script is like a `__dirname` can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`process.cwd` method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) ?

You can simply call it with `process.cwd()` and it will return the current working directory.

IIRC, you don't even need to import `process` to call it.